# Detect View or PartialView in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In a controller can I detect if I'm "controlling" a View or a partial view?

I have a shared controller that sits between any controller and `Controller`, there are things I would only like to happen if its a View rather than a partial view.

Ideally in `protected override ViewResult View(...`

Comment: In what scenario would you not already know this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check

> ControllerContext.IsChildAction

in your action method, or

> filterContext.IsChildAction

in OnActionExecuted

Comment: Very nice function. This saves me a lot of processing in my code because I have a BaseController which all my controllers inherits and in my BaseController, I create in the Initialize function my menus. In this case, when my View had 3 Partial Views, the menu was constructed 3 times. I can now check if the IsChildAction is false for constructing menu and that's it! Thank you.

Comment: This only works if a Partial is called withing a View. Does not work if an Action is called directly, like from a route. I have MVC render partial views for popups, and call them directly.

Answer (score 1):

Have a different route for each. /home/about and /home/about/partial that both are routed to the same controller method. Basically, rather than trying to sniff around for things, EXPRESS it explicitly, through a route, or parameter.

Comment: because its huge and I don't fancy retro fitting something that involves changing every route in the solution.